# How do you change C++ class autocomplete in VS Code so that the public keyword appears first?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When autocompleting a class in C++ on VS code, it will print private first and public second. I would like to change the defaults to the opposite but I cannot find where to access these settings. Is there a key you can set in the c_cpp_properties.json file maybe?

Comment: The C++ formatter that VS Code offers is sorely lacking, and that's to say the least. You'd be much more happy using **"CLang"**'s tools. You can locate the formatter under the name **"CLang Format"**, and the linter under **CLang Tidy**,

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I thought that [CLang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) had a setting like the one you asked for. I looked through the link above's documentation (which I know fairly well) for a rule that organizes the access modifiers, but there doesn't seem to be one. I also poked around VS Code, and to no ones supprise, VS Code didn't have anything worth mentioning either.

#### There is Good Option that Might Work for You Though.

This solution is called **[VS Code Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)**. The snippets are what you are using when you click the suggestion that auto completes. The template that creates the class is defined in the Snippet `cpp.json` document, or if you downloaded a snippets extension for C++ they might live their. Either way, you can just write your own ***"C++ Class Snippet"***,and use that. The snippet will be auto completed in what ever manner you define it. Here is one I wrote, to demonstrate what you can do:

**FYI:** You are already using snippets each time you use an auto-completion, your just using snippets that someone else wrote.

[image: Creating custom Snippets and fixing VS Code Auto-completion]

IMO, VSCode has the best support, by far, for writing auto completions.

```
 "C++ Class Snippet (public first) @JCSB": {
        "prefix": "class",
        "body":[
            "class ${0:Name} {",
            "\npublic:",
            "\n  ${1:publicMember}", // PUBLIC MEMBERS
            "\n  ${2:publicMember}",
            "\n  ${3:publicMember}",
            "\nprivate:",
            "\n  ${4:privateMember}", // PRIVATE MEMBERS
            "\n  ${5:privateMember}",
            "\n  ${6:privateMember}",
            "\nprotected:",
            "\n  ${7:protectedMember}", // PROTECTED MEMBERS
            "\n};"
        ],
        "description": "(@JCSB) C++ class w/ public access modifier placed first."
    }
```

###### The class has 4 Place holders (`$0`, `$1`, `$2` & `$3`).

- **$0:** *"choose class name"*
- **$1:** *"Set your public members"*
- **$2:** *"Set your private members"*
- **$3:** *"Author your methods."*

You can move from one placeholder to the next using the Tab key.

**HELPFULL LINKS:**

1. ###### [Official Snippets Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)
2. ###### [You should read about Emmets as well at the link below:](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)
3. ###### [Read about configuring the "V.S. Code Intellisense Extension".](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) *This page will tell you how to configure it, which is an advanced topic with information that is capable of changing the way you look at V.S. Code & how you use its tools & features.*

---

###### *One Last Tip:*

Add the following configurations to your `settings.json` file to make sure your snippets take priority over suggestions and built-in snippets in the suggestions-widget. Quick suggestions is a suggested word, or syntax that intellisense puts at the top. Those who write there own snippets often find it useful to prioritize their snippets over the quick suggestions.

```
// @file "settings.json"

{
   "editor.snippetSuggestions": "inline",
   "editor.suggest.showSnippets": true,
   "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": true,
}
```